# How to force line-breaks on &nbsp;?

Tags: php, html, text

Sometimes text on my pages looks very strange, real example:

```
trained&nbsp;professionals&nbsp;and&nbsp;paraprofessionals&nbsp;coming together
```

...While the parent div is quite narrow so the text is just sticking out of it.

And it looks quite strange, because `&nbsp;` actually represents a space.

So, I wonder if it's possible to make the browser account these characters as actual spaces and break the line where necessary without actually replacing them?

**EDIT**

Why a blind replacing is a problem?

Because `&nbsp;` may be needed sometimes.

Consider the following example:

```
Ranks:<br>
&nbsp;Marshall<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;Leutenant<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sergeant
```

If I just use a `preg_replace` on them it would look differently in the end.

(I would also consider some suggestions if you have any ideas on replacing them smartly (for php platform) If you could think of some algorithm that wouldn't affect formatting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[By definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), `&nbsp;` is a non-breakable space. It's very meaning is not to be broken across line endings. If this is not what you intend then I suggest fixing the HTML instead of trying to force the browser into non-standard behaviour.

Comment: Well, its not quite easy to fix, because I can't see them in my wysiwyg editors.

Comment: Don't your WYSIWYG editors support editing the HTML directly? You can also use any standard text editor to replace `&nbsp;` by a normal space. Or try to find out why your WYSIWYG editor produces the non-breakable spaces in the first place -- perhaps there is an option to disable them?

Comment: Well it's probably due to the fact that I copy paste the html pages from other sites. It keeps the formatting and even keeps the images and all, the only problem are spaces. I'm using latest tinymce. It might be a good idea though, to mod it to be able to clear these &nbsp; characters before I actually submit a form.

Comment: Your are right, it looks like a Tinymce problem. It inserts `&nbsp;` in some places for some reason when I copy paste the html. The original files do not have these characters in them.